# Reasons for scratching the wall of a flask when precipitate crystals

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I heard that scratching the wall of the flask helps precipitate crystals when obtaining crystals.
By scratching the wall of the flask, the crystals from it fall in the center and act as seeds to help produce crystals?
So, can it be said that the process of scratching the walls of the flask induces heterogeneous nucleation and helps crystallization?
To understand this, would it be helpful to study 'crystallization (creation of crystalline nuclei and growth of crystals)?
Will this process of scratching the wall of the flask ultimately help increase the yield?

Comment: Because nucleation is a very rare event (after all, you need a single nucleus for making crystalls with millions of particles in them), and very hard to study. It is possible that all nucleation events are heterogeneous (you need to have crystalls forming in a containerless droplet without any impurities such as dust to have a valid counterexample that could be homogeneous nucleation - and it still could happen on the surface).

Comment: How do you define yield? Size of crystalls, or total mass of crystals. For large crystalls, you need a single nucleus - too effective nucleation would be counterproductive.

Comment: If your product is most stable as a solid (at ambient conditions) and you want to harvest/recuperate this product by filtration from a liquid/solution, the more crystalline precipitate staying to top of your Buchner filter, the higher the yield based on isolated material.  This obviously does not affect the yield based on conversion of the reagents.